# Sorting a list of based on the 2nd element of a tuple

Tags: list, sorting, erlang, tuples

I have a dictionary and want to convert it to a list. Then I would like to sort the resulting list consisting of {Key, Value} pairs from min to max depending on the 2nd element(Value).

Is there a built in sort method for Lists to handle this or how does one do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way to sort by the second element would be to define your own sorting function that could work as follows:

```
fun({KeyA,ValA}, {KeyB,ValB}) -> {ValA,KeyA} =< {ValB,KeyB} end.
```

And call it in `lists:sort/2`:

```
1> lists:sort(fun({KeyA,ValA}, {KeyB,ValB}) -> {ValA,KeyA} =< {ValB,KeyB} end., [{a,b},{b,a},{b,b}]).
[{b,a},{a,b},{b,b}]
```

This is because Erlang will always automatically compare tuples from first to last element. This function swaps the first and the second element so the second one acts as the first point of comparison. The Key in your dict will then be used to order entries where values are the same.

Comment: Nice1. Will this work for key value pairs of [{1, 14}, {3, 10}, {2, 13} ? Integers? Thanks

Comment: This will work for any value. Erlang terms are always comparable one to another. If your tuple has two values and you want the second one to lead, the function above will cover these cases. You could just try it and see.

Comment: Thanks once again for the help. appreciate it.

Comment: What if I wanted to sort and the only return a list of the First elements?

Comment: `[Key ||  {Key, _Val} <- List].`

Comment: I did the following:  `A = {1, 99}, B = {5, 15}.`  `F = fun({key_X, val_X},{key_Y, val_Y}) -> {val_X, key_X} =< {val_Y, key_Y} end.` And then, put it to `lists:sort/2` function. As follows: `lists:sort(F, [A, B]).` But got the error exception : `** exception error: no function clause matching erl_eval:'-inside-an-interpreted-fun-'({1,99},{5,15})`

Comment: @IGIVETERRIBLEADVICE Can you explain `[Key ||  {Key, _Val} <- List].` in more details (e.g. in function)? Thanks beforehand!

Comment: @elgolondrino this basically just returns a list of all the keys. The error you received, however, is due to the fact that you used names like `key_Y`, which are atoms. Variables would require using `KeyY`, where they are case sensitive. Lowercase = atom, Uppercase = variable.

Answer (score 13):

The function [lists:keysort/2](http://erldocs.com/R13B03/stdlib/lists.html?search=lists:keysort&i=0#keysort/2) fits like glove for this.

`1> lists:keysort(2, [{a,b},{b,a},{b,b}]).`

`[{b,a},{a,b},{b,b}]`

`2> lists:keysort(2, [{1,14},{3,10},{2,13}]).`

`[{3,10},{2,13},{1,14}]`

Comment: Awesome. Completely overlooked that. :/

Comment: What if I wanted to sort and the only return a list of the First elements?

Comment: Because the nature of sorting the element sorted on can't be discarded prematureley. Therefor you have to break this up into two steps; Sort and then run: `[ Key || {Key,Value} <- L ]` or the corresponding lists:map/2 function.

Comment: Upvoting. Your function's the right one for this case. I'm leaving my answer up because it will also finish the sorting on the key if the values are equal.