# Erlang list question

Tags: list, erlang, tuples

I have a list with tuples in Erlang for example:

```
[{1, "AAA"}, {2, "AAA"}, {3, "AAAAAAAA"}]
```

How can i get tuple from this list with max first element from this tuples?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [lists:keysort/2](http://erldocs.com/R13B03/stdlib/lists.html?search=lists:keysort&i=0#keysort/2).

`1> lists:keysort(1, [{1, "AAA"}, {2, "AAA"}, {3, "AAAAAAAA"}]).`

[Another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4370123/sorting-a-list-of-based-on-the-2nd-element-of-a-tuple/4371009#4371009)

edit: Seems I read your questions to fast. If you only want one tuple containing a maximum value and your tuples are of same size Arjan should be the accepted answer.

If you only want one term() element containing a maximum value, and if the rule with similar tuple-sizes Arjan stated doesn't apply, I would go with either a  `lists:foldl/3` or own recursion function.

Sorting the whole list is unnecessary unless you want the whole list sorted. My mistake.

Answer (score 5):

In this case [lists:max/1](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html#max-1) will return what you want.
For this to work all tuples must have the same number of elements.