# Sorting tuples based on elements in Erlang

Tags: sorting, erlang

Having read current answer [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4370123/sorting-a-list-of-based-on-the-2nd-element-of-a-tuple?rq=1) I did the following:

```
A = {1, 99}, B = {5, 15}.
F = fun({key_X, val_X},{key_Y, val_Y}) -> 
       {val_X, key_X} =< {val_Y, key_Y} 
    end.
```

And then, put it to `lists:sort/2` function. 
As follows:

```
lists:sort(F, [A, B]).
```

But got the error exception :

> exception error: no function clause matching erl_eval:'-inside-an-interpreted-fun-'({1,99},{5,15})

What is a mistake here? Can you guide me through?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to note that Erlang differentiates *atoms* and *identifiers* using their case.
Eg:

- `[a, b, bla, key_1, val_X]` is a list of **atoms**
- `[A, B, Bla, Key_1, Val_X]` is a list of **variables**

In your code you defined `F` so that it behaves a certain way *for specific atoms as input*.
What you should have done (and what they did in your link) is use variable identifiers:

`F = fun({Key_X, Val_X},{Key_Y, Val_Y}) -> {Val_X, Key_X} =< {Val_Y, Key_Y} end.`

See?